# MySQL Connector/Python - insert python variable to MySQL table

Tags: python, mysql, insert, mysql-connector-python

I'm trying to insert a python variable into a MySQL table within a python script but it is not working.  Here is my code

```
add_results=("INSERT INTO account_cancel_predictions"
            "(account_id,21_day_probability,flagged)"
            "Values(%(account_id)s,%(21_day_probability)s,%(flagged)s)")

data_result={
    'account_id':result[1,0],
    '21_day_probability':result[1,1],
    'flagged':result[1,2]
}

cursor.execute(add_results,data_result)

cnx.commit()
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

This gets the error

```
ProgrammingError: Failed processing pyformat-parameters; 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_float64_to_mysql'
```

However, when I replace the variable names `result[1,0]`, `result[1,1]`, and `result[1,2]` with their actual numerical values it does work.  I suspect python is passing the actual variable names rather than the values they hold.  How do I fix this?

Comment: connection = engine.connect() 
    connection.execute(""" update Players set Gold =(?) where Name=(?)""",(gold,name))  , maybe just a fanboy thing but I tend to use sqlalchemy with python and this tends to simplify much of this and I've never had issues using wildcards with it

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming you are using `mysql.connector` (I think you are), define your own converter class:

```
class NumpyMySQLConverter(mysql.connector.conversion.MySQLConverter):
    """ A mysql.connector Converter that handles Numpy types """

    def _float32_to_mysql(self, value):
        return float(value)

    def _float64_to_mysql(self, value):
        return float(value)

    def _int32_to_mysql(self, value):
        return int(value)

    def _int64_to_mysql(self, value):
        return int(value)

config = {
    'user'    : 'user',
    'host'    : 'localhost',
    'password': 'xxx',
    'database': 'db1'
}

conn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
conn.set_converter_class(NumpyMySQLConverter)
```

Comment: Nice solution! However, I had to include a `__init__` function in order for it to work. It might be because of my version. I used something similar to the original `MySQLConverter` class in `conversion.py`.

Comment: Where does one put this code? In a Jupyter notebook, in the mysql-connector library... ? I'm not familiar enough with mysql-connector or OOP in general to know. LIkewise, where would an `__init__` go? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093950/avoid-mysqlconverter-object-has-no-attribute-timestamp-to-mysql-error-with

Answer (score 7):

One of your passed values could be of type `numpy.float64` which is not recognized by the MySQL connector. Cast it to a genuine python `float` on populating the dict.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on python 3 and above, just use mysqlclient `pip install mysqlclient`. It is recommended by django and all the other drivers are bad.

Comment: It can be annoying (in my opinion) to deal with spinning up cloud resources that support mysqlclient if the use-case doesn't require the C++ optimization. This is a niche scenario, but I'd rather wrangle my data types than deal with mysql installation in serverless resources if I don't need to.