# How does one convert from mysql to python types using msqyl-connector

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I know how to create a converter from python types to mysql types when using mysql-connector (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19502805/1518546).

However, how do I override the default conversion from mysql to python. For instance, if I would like Decimal types in mysql to just be a float instead of a python Decimal type?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the code, the pattern for the functions to override is: `_TYPE_to_python`. What was not intuitive was the type names. You may find them as follows:

```
import mysql.connector
for item in mysql.connector.constants.FieldType.desc:
     print(item)
```

Which produces something like:

```
NULL
DATETIME
DATE
LONG
GEOMETRY
LONGLONG
TINY
NEWDECIMAL
BIT
MEDIUM_BLOB
SET
YEAR
LONG_BLOB
VARCHAR
VAR_STRING
TINY_BLOB
FLOAT
TIMESTAMP
NEWDATE
DOUBLE
INT24
SHORT
DECIMAL
TIME
BLOB
STRING
ENUM
```

So, to return a Decimal as a float, you would override the `_DECIMAL_to_python` and/or the `__NEWDECIMAL_to_python` methods. When which one is used, I don't know.