# Python 'float64' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to store some data in MYSQL workbench database using python script, but I got the following error when I am trying to insert (anomaly_low, anomaly_medium, anomaly_high) in the database.

```
Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'float64' cannot be converted to a MySQL type.
```

Actually, I am extracting some data from my DB and give them as arguments to a function. And, use the value returned by the function for another query. My code is:

```
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib
 import skfuzzy as fuzz
 from skfuzzy import control as ctrl
 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
 import mysql.connector
 from mysql.connector import Error
 from mysql.connector import errorcode
 import time
 import datetime

 try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='1111',
                                       database='x',
                                       user='x',
                                       password='xx')
cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)
anomaly = (a.compute_anomaly(85, 5))
print(anomaly) 
test = str(a.get_anomaly(anomaly))[1:-1]
print(test)
t = test.split(',')
anomaly_low = t[0]
anomaly_medium = t[1]
anomaly_high = t[2]
print (anomaly_low )
print (anomaly_medium ) 
print (anomaly_high ) 
ts = time.time()
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 
 %H:%M:%S')


 #insert data to fuzzy_anomaly
sql_anomaly = "INSERT INTO fuzzy_anomaly(anomaly,anomaly_low, 
anomaly_medium, anomaly_high,timestamp)  VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"

input = (anomaly, anomaly_low, anomaly_medium, anomaly_high,timestamp)
cursor.execute(sql_anomaly , input, multi=True)
connection.commit()

print("1 record inserted, ID:", cursor.lastrowid)

except mysql.connector.Error as error :
    print("Failed to update record to database: {}".format(error))
    connection.rollback()
finally:
    #closing database connection.
    if(connection.is_connected()):
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

these are my fields/ columns names in my database. I am trying to insert `anomaly`, `anomaly_low`, `anomaly_medium`, `anomaly_high`, `timestamp` data into MYSQL.

[image]

But, when I manually give arguments to the `compute_anomaly(arg1, arg2)` function, and delete the first query (`input_fuzzy`)  the error goes away.
Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correct indentation is important in Python, please fix your posted code (`try`, `except`, and `finally` blocks need to be indented). Also, Python doesn't allow you to wrap lines in strings, unless you use triple quotes.

Comment: What is that `for i` loop doing? It never uses `i`, and keeps overwriting the same variable `t`. It seems like it could be replaced with `t = test.split(',')`

Comment: @Barmar In my code, I have the correct indentation. And I did not wrap lines. It is my first time asking a question here and sorry if I wrote the code in this way. For your second question, get_anomaly(anomaly) return a list with 3 elements, which I want to insert them separately in the database.

Comment: Paste your formatted code, then indent it 4 columns using `Ctl-k` or the `{}` tool in the SO editor to mark it as code.

Comment: If it returns a list with 3 elements, why don't you just use list indexing instead of turning it into a string then splitting it?

Comment: `t = a.get_anomaly(anomaly)`

Comment: @Barmar I edited my code and deleted "for" line. but I still have this error.

Comment: I don't know why you're getting that error, my comments are not really related to it.

Comment: Is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053435/mysql-connector-python-insert-python-variable-to-mysql-table/19502805) helpful?

Comment: @Barmar yes thanks, the error went away. It says 1 record inserted but the DB is empty.

Comment: What does it say after `ID:`? Does that row exist?

Comment: @Barmar it says:1 record inserted, ID: 0